# Google Visualization API series data in rows not columns. Pivot?

Tags: google-visualization

I have JSON data in the following format.

How do I pivot the data and create a Google line chart with series lines for each Staff member?

```
[
["DTS","Staff","Score"],
["2020-01-01","Ron",12],
["2020-01-01","Bob",7],
["2020-01-02","Ron",1],
["2020-01-03","Bob",4]
]
```

I would like a line graph showing 2 series (Ron & Bob) across the date range.
There could be many "Staff" members across multiple dates.
I am familiar with how the google charts API works but I am having difficulty getting this data in the correct format as all examples I have found have the series data in columns not rows.

Most Examples show data in this format:

```
[
["DTS","Ron","Bob"],
["2020-01-01",12,7],
["2020-01-02",1,0],
["2020-01-03",0,4]
]
```

I have attempted to follow [Google Visualization API Chart - Line Charts using columns or rows like series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20196945/google-visualization-api-chart-line-charts-using-columns-or-rows-like-series) but with no joy.